# Inkscape: How to exclude multiple object from selection

Tags: inkscape, selections

I can't realize how to exclude multiple object from selection (using selection rectangle).

Example: I have a table where are borders (long lines - paths) and some text (every character is single path object). I want to make group from long lines (borders).

So, I select whole table and want to deselect text objects. I can hold `shift` and click on every object to exclude from selection (~1000 clicks? - please no!).

Thanks for your advice.

PS: Now, I'm using a workaround - select the text objects and group them, then select whole table and exclude few text groups by single clicks.

Comment: Welcome Lluser! Thanks for posting your question. Unfortunately, GD.SE is not designed to handle issues regarding technical support or basic software education. If you are seeking technical assistance with an application, please try the application manufacture's web site. If you are seeking to learn how to accomplish something within an application, please review the application help files or try an internet search with your question or an internet search for a tutorial. We are confident you will find answers.

Comment: Ok, i'm sorry for useless question. I assumed, there is analogue of SuperUser forums for graphical application. I search web for hours before asking, but any manual or article what I found didn't contain any new information (for me) about this. Also there is several similar (technical and application focused) question with good rating. Have nice day :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on how your document is constructed, there are three Inkscape features that might help you here.

1. **Layers** are your friend -- Add the items that you want to not be selected into a new layer, and use the Lock feature on that layer to stop them being selected. For more info on layers, see: http://en.flossmanuals.net/inkscape/ch036_layers/
2. The second is a little known feature of the Select Tool, called **Touch Selection**. Holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and clicking and dragging with the select tool draws a temporary red line on your canvas -- anything that intersects with the red line is selected. For more info on all the features of the select tool, see: http://en.flossmanuals.net/inkscape/ch006_select-tool/
3. Finally, a new Feature in Inkscape 0.91 is **Select Same**. This allows you to select objects that are the same object type, or have the same fill, or stroke values. This will allow you to select all the paths/lines in your document, but not select the text. For more info see: https://inkscapetutorials.org/2013/09/05/inkscape-0-49-feature-selecting-objects-by-style/

Answer (score 0):

Three relative ideas :

1. Another possibility is to lock / move to a locked layer the objects you want to exclude.
2. In some cases, the find/replace panel is of some help to select precise objects.
3. Notice that selections can somehow be saved using css and selector panel.

Answer (score -1):

The strict answer to your question "how to exclude multiple object from selection, using selection rectangle?" is you can't.
This is a, sadly, a missing feature of Inkscape (like undoing/redoing selection changes!).

Comment: Yes you can. With the Selector Tool, you can hold down shift and click on objects to remove them from a selection.